# Spring 2.0 XML PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer System.getProperty("user.dir")

Tags: java, xml, spring, properties, system

I am currently trying to write an XML file, which uses the path of "System.getProperty("user.dir")". I am using Spring 2.0 and have following code, which I want to edit so that I can somehow call the user.dir path, this example should only show what I want to do with the XML file, of course it does not work like this:

```
<bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
        <property name="locations">
            <list>
            <value>file:System.getProperty("user.dir")/PATH...</value>  
            <value>file:System.getProperty("user.dir")/PATH...</value>
            </list>
        </property>             
   </bean>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay so I just found the answer by combining different approaches from other websites:

```
<bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
    <property name="locations">
        <list>
        <value>file:${user.dir}/PATH...</value>  
        <value>file:${user.dir}/PATH...</value>
        </list>
    </property>
```